# Cpp/ C++ unique Pointer on objects access functions of that class

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

How do I access functions via a unique pointer pointing on an object of that class

```
struct foo
{
    foo(int);
    void getY();
};

int main()
{
    foo f1(1);
    f1.getY();
    std::unique_ptr<foo> ptr1 = make_unique<foo>(2);
    *ptr1.getY(); // Error
};
```

*foo has a constructor with an int as argument,`getY()` just prints out that int value.*

Obviously   `foo f1(1); f1.getY();` works but idk how to access `getY()` over the pointer.  `unique_ptr<foo> ptr1 = make_unique<foo>(2); *ptr1.getY();`
was my initial idea, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `(*ptr1).getY();` or `ptr1->getY();` (as regular pointer).

Comment: Or just `ptr1->getY();`. Your version almost works, but the dot has higher [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than dereferencing. So `*ptr1.getY();` gets interpreted as `*(ptr1.getY());` instead of `(*ptr).getY();`

Comment: Just wondering where you heard about pointers but not about how to use them. Don't wanna be mean here, but the effort to create an account on StackOverflow, ask a question, wait for answers and then read those answers is higher than to just read the example in the tutorial, book, or whatever gave you the idea of pointers.

Comment: @StefanRiedel lmao, it's part of an assignment and my knowledge is pretty pieced together from all sorts of sources and missing some parts as you can tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is that due to **operator precedence** when you wrote `*ptr1.getY();`, it was **equivalent** to writing:

```
*(ptr1.getY());
```

So this means you're trying to call a member function named  `getY` on the smart pointer `ptr1` but since `ptr1` has no member function called `getY` you get the error.

To **solve** this you should write:

```
( *ptr1 ).getY();//works now
```

This time you're specifically asking/grouping `*ptr` together and then calling the member function `getY` on the resulting object . And since the resulting object is of type `foo` which has a member function `getY`, this works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use it as an ordinary pointer. For example

```
( *ptr1 ).getY();
```

or

```
ptr1->getY();
```

Or even like:)

```
p.get()->getY();
( *p.get() ).getY();
```

That is there are declared the following operators and the accessor in the class template `unique_ptr`

```
add_lvalue_reference_t<T> operator*() const;
pointer operator->() const noexcept;
pointer get() const noexcept;
```